# sending data view to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**my view**

```
<div class="dropdown1">
    <button class="dropbtn1">Asia</button>
    <div class="dropdown1-content">
        <li>
            <ul style="height:520px; overflow: auto">
                <?php foreach ($result as $row) {?>
                    <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/MyWeb_Controller/countriesView/<?php echo $row['count_name']?>">
                    <?php echo $row['count_name'];?>    
                    </a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </div>
</div>
```

**my controller**

```
public function countriesView($a){
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('Country_View');
var_dump($a);die();
```

}

the result is show like this
string(12) "%20%20BRUNEI"
i want to show only the country name 'BRUNEI'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use - (dash) instant of space because space value change in url like %20%. Try the following code i have replace space to - in view and revert it on controller

View :

```
<div class="dropdown1">
    <button class="dropbtn1">Asia</button>
    <div class="dropdown1-content">
        <li>
            <ul style="height:520px; overflow: auto">
                <?php foreach ($result as $row) {?>
                    <li>
                      <?php $county_name = str_replace(' ','-',$row['count_name']); ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/MyWeb_Controller/countriesView/<?php echo $county_name; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['count_name'];?>    
                    </a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
public function countriesView($a){
   $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->view('Country_View');
   $a = str_replace('-',' ',$a);
   var_dump($a);die():
}
```

Comment: when i send data like this it show in the link.can i hide it?